# What's the best way to use regex in searching for files named via some pattern in linux?

Tags: regex, find

I have file names that are named thusly...

```
[phone_number]_[email]_[milliseconds].mp4
```

so:

```
2125551212_foo@blah.com_1378447385902.mp4
```

`find` takes a regex pattern (supposedly) 
to look for files that start with 10 digits and end with `mp4`like this:

```
find ../media_pool -regex '^\d{10}.*mp4$'
```

However that returns nothing at all.

When I try it thusly:
    find ../media_pool -regex 'mp4$'
it returns all the files that end with that extension... so, it *looks like it works with some subset of regex but not all.

Can someone point me to what the right way to get what I need would be? I'm happy not to use find if something else does the job better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in Linux utilities but it seems you can specify the type of the regex used to match the pattern, anyway it seems that `\d` is not supported, try the following:

```
find ../media_pool -regextype posix-extended -regex '^[0-9]{10}.*mp4$'
```

I don't know if you need to quote `posix-extended`, that's for you to figure out.

**Edit:** Sorry for that, there was another problem. You don't need to change the engine type, by default `find` uses `Emacs` engine and I was able to look at the syntax supported.

```
find ../media_pool -regex '.*/[0-9]\{10\}.*mp4$'
```

The key is escaping the { and } eg. `\{10\}` and adding a .*/ to the start to match on the full path which find returns.

Comment: It doesn't complain about anything being wrong, but still doesn't find my files, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sniffer Why aren't you testing things before posting them as an answer?

Comment: `find ../media_pool -regex '.*/[0-9]\{10\}.*mp4$'` works! so apparently the issue a combination of my missing the leading path in the result and... umm... no, I guess that was it

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Here is the thing, I am working on Windows and testing them using RegexBuddy and they are working fine for my test strings, but the actual tool may have some difference and some context which I don't know of.

Comment: I edited your answer with the minor adjustment to make it works. thanks again.

Comment: @GeniaS. Great, that's fine by me. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure out that find matches the entire path, so you need the ".*/" at the beginning. The following is tested and works.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{10}.*mp4$'
```

Comment: on my system the { and } also required escaping for this to finally work and -regextype was not recognized, so, perhaps my version of find (on the Mac) doesn't support it?

Answer (score 0):

The default regular expression engine for *find* is Emacs, you can change it to something else by using the *-regextype* option

Here is an example using *sed*:

```
find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/[0-9]\{10\}.*mp4$"
```

there are most likely other solutions since several engines are supported. Another important thing to note is the `.*/` at the beginning of the regular expression, *find* matches the entire path of a file so this will catch that.